# Tabby Long Hair 3 Month old Girl

Tags: cats

Hello fellow animal lovers
Is it safe to give a 3 month old kitten caster oil as a preventative for hair ball? Or is brushing her enough? How about the type of Cat litter? I started her on soft wood clumping and placed three seperate trays for her in different parts of the house she is very clean. Plus, I started growing cat grass for her and catnip. The cat nip died but the cat grass is thriving only just. She seems to like to sit on it and gently takes some out and chews on it I cant tell for sure if she swallows it. Is it safe to leave a three month old kitten at home on her own for a few hours leaving her lots of water bowls, dry and wet partly cooked and some store bought. Any suggestions or experiences warmly welcome. M

Comment: Hi Monica, welcome to Pets; I'm really glad and happy that you had such a nice first impression with our site, it reminds me of how I myself have fallen in love at first sight with Pets SE a few months ago and stayed since then. Please see [tour] page for a short tutorial how this site operates; most important thing is, this is Q&A site and it works differently than general discussion forums - it means that all posts must contain a clearly stated question or answer.

Comment: Also, you could participate in [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) for a more relaxed talk about pets. All people could read the chat, but one needs to have accumulated at least 20 reputation to write on chat. If one is active on the site and creates useful answers and questions, it takes a really short time to reach these reputation thresholds needed to talk on chat or write replies in comments. Happy New Year!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question. Stack Exchange is a question-and-answer format site, not an open discussion forum.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You don't send replies here in the sense of a discussion. One person writes a question (like you did) then other people provide answers. Clarifications are made in comments. People up-vote what they consider to be good answers. After people have answered, you may choose any one answer that you think the best and used the tick symbol to accept it.

Comment: ...  A suitable question might be - *"On 29 December 2020 I bought a 12 week old female kitten -  I have had her for one month (4) weeks she is very playful but seems to hiss at me and growl - also sometimes loud sudden noises from outside like traffic and other noises frighten her and so she runs and hides.  Do I need to worry? How should I make sure she is happy?"*  You can, if you wish, forget about this question and submit another with a title like, **New kitten hisses and growls and is scared of loud noises"**  -  I hope that helps :-)

Comment: No problem thank you I changed the question really new to this so I removed the original first question that didnt turn out the way  I had hoped. How can I post a question about kitten if I can leave her alone for a few hours and if its safe to give her castor oil to prevent hair balls and what is the best litter material I used the soft wood clumping she seems to like it ... is it a good one or should I use clay or crystals ?

Comment: Thank you Allison C yesterday. Have a nice day

Comment: thank you chasly I am still learning how to navigate the site/s. I appreciate your input. Yes, I shall endear to forget about all the questions I post. I will see if I can reply if I am sure about the answer and if I have free time to spare. God bless.

Comment: Thank you lilla its delightful to see you have a sense of humor. Great weekend to you and godspeed.

Comment: The best thing to do is first do a search to see if your questions have already been answered; there are many existing questions here with very well-researched answers that you can look to for answers to your own questions. If you can't find the answer you need, then you can ask a single question at a time (so just "what litter should I use?" though I believe that already has a few answers here). Welcome to Pets!